# Yii2 gridview date range picker filter won't function

Tags: gridview, yii2, kartik-v

I have added kartik-v date range picker to my gridview but the filter cannot work after I select the date. The placeholder of the widget will show the selected date but the result in the gridview does not match. The result in the gridview shows all data.

Code in the view :

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'options' => ['class' => 'table-sm'],
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'summary' =>'',
    'columns' => [
        [
            'attribute' => 'price',
            'value' => function ($model) {
                return number_format($model->price, 3);
            },
            'contentOptions' => ['class' => 'text-right']
        ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'date',
            'contentOptions' => ['class' => 'text-right'],
            'filter' => DateRangePicker::widget([
                'name'=>'date_range_2',
                'presetDropdown'=>true,
                'convertFormat'=>true,
                'includeMonthsFilter'=>true,
                'attribute' => 'date',
                'model' => $searchModel,
                'pluginOptions' => ['locale' => ['format' => 'Y-m-d']],
                'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select Date']
            ])
        ],
    ]
]); ?>
```

Below code is my $searchModel part.
Updated:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['id'], 'integer'],
        [['name', 'date'], 'safe'],
        [['price'], 'number'],
    ];
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function scenarios()
{
    // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
    return Model::scenarios();
}

/**
 * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
 *
 * @param array $params
 *
 * @return ActiveDataProvider
 */
public function search($params)
{
    $query = Lme::find()->orderBy([
        'date' => SORT_DESC
    ]);

    // add conditions that should always apply here

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'sort' => false //['defaultOrder' => ['date' => SORT_DESC]]
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {

        return $dataProvider;
    }

    // grid filtering conditions
    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'id' => $this->id,
        'price' => $this->price,
        'date' => $this->date,
    ]);

    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'name', $this->name]);


    return $dataProvider;
    }
```

Comment: Show your `$searchModel`

Answer (score 1):

The DateRangePicker itself gives you a string with the range, so a simple where clause with `'date' => $this->date` can not work. Kartik V. provides a behavior `kartik\daterange\DateRangeBehavior` in the package `kartik-v/yii2-date-range`.

I'm using it in the following way successfully. Note that my timestamp attribute is `timestamp_visit`.

In the view:

```
echo GridView::widget([
...
    'columns' => [
        [
            'attribute' => 'timestamp_visit',
            'format' => [
                'datetime',
                'medium'
            ],
            'width' => '60px',
            'filterType' => GridView::FILTER_DATE_RANGE,
            'filterWidgetOptions' => [
                'model' => $searchModel,
                'convertFormat' => true,
                'pluginOptions' => [
                    'timePicker' => true,
                    'timePickerIncrement' => 1,
                    'timePicker24Hour' => true,
                    'locale' => [
                        'format' => $searchModel::TIME_FORMAT,
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ],
    ...
    ]
```

In the search model:

```
<?php
...
use kartik\daterange\DateRangeBehavior;

class ...Search extends ....
{
    const TIME_FORMAT = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';

    /**
     * @var string Start date filled up by DateRangeBehavior
     */     
    public $timestampVisitStart;

    /**         
     * @var string End date filled up by DateRangeBehavior
     */         
    public $timestampVisitEnd;
...

       public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['timestamp_visit'], 'match', 'pattern' => '/^.+\s\-\s.+$/'],
            ...
        ];
    } 
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            [
                'class' => DateRangeBehavior::class,
                'attribute' => 'timestamp_visit',
                'dateStartAttribute' => 'timestampVisitStart',
                'dateEndAttribute' => 'timestampVisitEnd',
                'dateStartFormat' => self::TIME_FORMAT,
                'dateEndFormat' => self::TIME_FORMAT,
            ]
        ];
    }
...
    public function search($params)
    {
        $query = self::find();

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query
        ]);

        $dataProvider->sort = new Sort([
            'defaultOrder' => [
                'timestamp_visit' => SORT_DESC,
                'id' => SORT_DESC,
            ]
        ]);
...
        if ($this->timestampVisitStart) {
            $query->andWhere(['>=', "timestamp_visit", $this->timeToUTC($this->timestampVisitStart)]);
        }
        if ($this->timestampVisitStart) {
            $query->andWhere(['<=', "timestamp_visit", $this->timeToUTC($this->timestampVisitEnd)]);
        }

        return $dataProvider;
   }

   /**
     * Convert string time in format $format to UTC time format for SQL where clause
     * @param string $time Time in format $format
     * @param string $format Format of $time for the function date, default 'Y-m-d H:i:s'
     */
    private function timeToUTC($time, $format='Y-m-d H:i:s')
    {
        $timezoneOffset = \Yii::$app->formatter->asDatetime('now', 'php:O');
        return date($format, strtotime($time.$timezoneOffset));
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to ask, the attribute that you use 'timestamp_visit' is from the db there which has the column named 'timestamp_visit', right? And also the 'timestampVisitStart' and 'timestampVisitEnd' also in the db? or you just declare in the searchModel?

Comment: Yes, `timestamp_visit` is a DB field of MySQL type `timestamp`. `timestampVisitStart` and `timestampVisitEnd` are declared of course only in the search model.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm sorry to ask again the "className()" in the behaviors function is refer to the which class? Because I'm now confusing about it. The "className" is just a declare use in this behavior or I need to change it to my Model class name?

Comment: `DateRangeBehavior::className()` returns the fully qualified classname of DateRangeBehavior, so use it as it is in my example. The behavior config needs the class name of the behavior to add it to the current model. Because `className()` is deprecated since Yii 2.0.14, I've changed it to `::class`. But it works also with `::className()`. You need to change `timestampVisit` and `timestamp_visit` everywhere in my example to `date`. That's all what you  need.

Comment: I have change what you told in my searchModel but in my GridView it still show all the result after I choose the certain date. Is there any affect from my searchModel function?--> "public function search($params)
{
    $query = Lme::find()->orderBy([
        'date' => SORT_DESC
    ]);

    // add conditions that should always apply here

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'sort' => false //['defaultOrder' => ['date' => SORT_DESC]]
    ]);"

Comment: Please, edit your original question, to hold the current search model and view code, to allow to help you. On the other side you could [debug](https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-debug) what happens. I guess the validation in your search model returns false and so no filtering applies.